# Android client Socket not connectig until write()

Tags: java, android, c, sockets

I have a problem with socket communication in Android app. After client call to Socket.connect(adr,time) nothing happens on server (written in C) side (accept() not returning new socket). Only when I write something to socket on the client side, communication starts and server sends welcome message. 
When I am using telnet everything works fine. Can somebody please explain to me why connect() method not connects until first write()?

So here is some explanation of problematic client code.
Communication starts after clicking this button in main activity:

```
  private View.OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){

            commTask = new TCPComm();
            commTask.execute();
      }
};
```

It executes new AsyncTask to communicate with server:

```
 public class TCPComm extends AsyncTask<Void, byte[], Boolean> {
    Socket commSock;
    InputStream netInStream;
    OutputStream netOutStream;
    BufferedReader inFromServer;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        outputText("Connecting to LightServer");

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        boolean result = false;
        String srvResponse;
        try {
            SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", XXXX);
            commSock = new Socket();
            commSock.setTcpNoDelay(true);
            commSock.connect(sockaddr, 5000);

                if (commSock.isConnected()) {

                netInStream = commSock.getInputStream();
                netOutStream = commSock.getOutputStream();

                inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(netInStream));
                while((srvResponse = inFromServer.readLine()) != null){
                    byte[] responseArray = srvResponse.getBytes();
                    publishProgress(responseArray);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = true;
        } finally {
            closeSocket();
        }
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(byte[]... values) {

        if (values.length > 0) {
            if (Arrays.equals(values[0],msgPIN)) {
                pin = pinEdit.getText().toString().trim()+"#";
                SendResponse(pin);

            }

            if (Arrays.equals(values[0],msgCOM)) {
                authenticated = true;
                relaySwitch.setEnabled(true);

            }

        }
    }

}
```

But this task does not make connection to server. Only when I write something to socket connection is established and server sends first message. 
I wrote simple java app only with this fragment of AsyncTask:

```
SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", XXXX);
commSock = new Socket();
commSock.setTcpNoDelay(true);
commSock.connect(sockaddr, 5000);
```

and it connects with no problems so i think that this issue is related to android and processing of AsyncTask

Comment: which library you are using in server side?

Comment: @thuovila There is no evidence for the contention in your edit. Rolled it back.

Comment: @EJP The server works OK with a known good client, i.e. telnet. That would suggest the problem lies in the client. However, I can concede it is possible the problem is still in the server. Still, it would be reasonable to tag with both used programming languages. It is absurd having an android java app question without java people answering it.

Comment: @ArturrO please make your question [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Include some code)

Comment: @thuovila We don't know where the problem is, but the rationale you gave for your edit, i.e. to quote you "OPs problem is actually in Java based own code, probably not in the C based server", is baseless. My own opinion is that either the OP isn't seeing what he thinks he's seeing or that he isn't executing the code he thinks he is, but mere opinions don't justify edits.

Comment: I was thinkig that this is some kind of known behaviour of Java sockets, thast why there is no code in my question :) Source coming soon...

Comment: Just one more remark. After nsocket.connect packet sniffer shows no traffic comming through the socket but nsocket.isConnected returns "true". Some kind of magic???

Answer (score 0):

:D I have found a solution. Everything works fine on mobile. On emulator this connections are broken. I think that this is related to NAT. In my test environment client running on emulator connects to server on LAN. Maybe someone can explain how to setup adb to work properly with this kind of connections?